# Slicing Cross-section of 2D NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

I'm looking to print a cross-section of a numpy array. I am looking to pull the first 15 rows and only data from the 5th index column.

```
import csv as csv
import numpy as np 

csv_file_object = open('train.csv', 'rU')
header = next(csv_file_object)
data = []

for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)

data = np.array(data)

print(data[0:15,5])
```

When I run the above code, I receive the following error: IndexError: too many indices for array.

Running the code without adding the column filter works as expected. The csv file is a 12x892 (x,y) dataset.

Comment: check your array shape, are you sure you don't have 12 columns and 892 rows?

Comment: Yes, it is 12 columns and 892 rows.

    print(data[0:15]) #prints all columns and rows 1-15
    print(data[0:15,5]) #receive IndexError

Answer (score 0):

The `csv_file_object` is a file object contains all lines of your csv file without splitting. You have to use `csv` module to read them properly:

```
with open('train.csv', 'rU') as csv_file_object:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file_object)
    data = np.array([row.values() for row in reader])
```

But since you want to convert them to a numpy array you better to use `genfromtxt` function:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('train.csv')
```

You can pass arguments like `dtype`, `delimiter` and `names` (a boolean for keeping the headers).

Comment: I imported with your method and still received the same IndexError. Why is it that when I include the the column filter (index 5), I receive the error and when it is left out it prints the first 15 rows as expected

Comment: @jmh1092 Maybe your array doesn't have 5 column.

Comment: what does data.shape return?

Comment: data.shape returns: (891,)

I see that it showing 'data' as a 1D array. Would I need to include a delimiter=',' when opening the csv file?

Comment: @jmh1092 Just, try it. (If you are sure it's the delimiter)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I did not call csv.reader() prior to opening the file

```
import csv as csv
import numpy as np 

csv_file_object = csv.reader(open('train.csv', 'rU'))
header = next(csv_file_object)
data = []

for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)

data = np.array(data)

print(data.shape)
print(data[0:15,5])
```